# Subdomain not reading modules or themes folder under sites/all/

Tags: drupal, themes, subdomain

I have a site set up with drupal, everything going fine.  I then added a subdomain, and that too was fine until I went to enable a custom theme that was under the sites/all/themes folder.  The theme does not show properly in the admin panel (no thumbnail), and when activated, the site appears to have no structure at all.

The theme I am trying to use works flawlessly on my other sites, so the theme itself is not a problem.  I noticed the same happens with modules under that all/ folder.  It is able to use anything under the root themes and modules folder however.

So something is preventing it from properly loading/reading the sites/all/ folder.  Dumping everything into the core folder is not ideal of course, but I can't figure out the problem.

Edit:  RESOLVED!
Somehow an htaccess file got into the sites folder with a redirect in it.  Causing just the subdomain to not see the subfolders properly, only root.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'added a subdomain'? Is it another site that is supposed to use the same Drupal instance?

Comment: Yes.  I have multisite running with both my main domain url and a subdomain.  Not the easiest thing set up, but this way I can have a shared drupal setup and database.

Answer (score 1):

If the themes and modules under `sites/all` are unavailable for both sites - the main site and your subdomain - then the problem may be around accessibility of the folder.

Regardless of the user account you use to access the site, it's almost certain that the website server itself (whether Apache, IIS or Xyz) runs as a different account. If that account doesn't have rights to scan for, and read, files under `sites/all` then they won't show up.

Compare the permissions (and user/group details, if running on a Unix server) between your regular `modules` directory and `sites/all` to find any differences, and fix any you find.

Comment: To your first point:  No, only with the subdomain site.
We eventually found there was an htaccess file in the sites folder that had a redirect.  So it was bouncing the subdomain and it couldn't see the themes folder properly.  Bizarre.  Thanks though!